# Coroutine Flow skips initial emit(Result.Loading) in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack-compose

I have Jetpack Compose CustomAlertDialog that depends on state change for recomposition. CustomAlertDialog contains TryAgain button that retries network call on Error with this function:

```
private val _systemList = MutableStateFlow<Result<List<SystemDomain>>>(Result.Loading)
val systemList: StateFlow<Result<List<SystemDomain>>> = _systemList

fun getSystemList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _systemList.emit(Result.Loading)
        val result = systemSelectionRepository.getSystemList()
        _systemList.emit(result)
    }
}
```

Problem is that sometimes _systemList.emit(Result.Loading) is not being emitted if _systemList.emit(result) as Result.Error is being called to fast, as only latest value is being collected.

By having Result.Error after Result.Error state, my CustomAlertDialog does not recompose itself.
My question is, how do I force emit(Result.Loading) to actually be emitted. One way is to do this, but it looks like a bad practice:

```
fun getSystemList() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        _systemList.emit(Result.Loading)
        delay(10)
        val result = systemSelectionRepository.getSystemList()
        _systemList.emit(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't be launching a coroutine to update a MutableStateFlow. Just use its value property _systemList.value = Result.Loading, other than that it may be because your initial vaule is Loading as StateFlow doesn't reemit same values.

Comment: if your `_systemList` is the same as in previous recomposition, how should your view change? Or are you talking that user press button and may not understand that it worked out when getting same error?

Comment: @J.Grbo My initial value is Result.Error, and after pressing TryAgain button, Result.Loading is skipped and Result.Error is emitted. This causes compose function to not recompose itself as previous state was the same.
I want to stop skipping Result.Loading

Comment: @mediumone The initial value of the _systemList is Result.Loading, private val _systemList = MutableStateFlow<Result<List<SystemDomain>>>(Result.Loading)